# Add a new persistent disk to GCE which created with VirtualBox custom image

Tags: google-compute-engine

I followed the tutorial google has up on youtube for creating a custom image for compute engine using VirtualBox by the link as follow

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YlcR6ZLebTM

I have succeed in created custom images and imported it to the Google Compute Engine.
But when I try to follow this document to attached a new persistent disk :

> https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/persistent-disks#attachdiskcreation

The document mentions a command line tool :

> /usr/share/google/safe_format_and_mount

but the folder /usr/share/google does not exist in my custom image.
How can I install it ? 
or is there another way to mount a new persistence disk in GCE instance
 ?

Answer (score 1):

The `/usr/share/google/safe_format_and_mount`command comes with the [Google Compute Engine image packages](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-packages). You can see the [source code here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-packages/blob/master/google-startup-scripts/usr/share/google/safe_format_and_mount).

You can either install the packages or run these commands:

1- Determine the device location of your new persistent disk: `ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/google-*`. Let's suppose it's /dev/sdb

2- `sudo mkfs.ext4 -E lazy_itable_init=0,lazy_journal_init=0 -F /dev/sdb`

3- `sudo mount -o discard,defaults /dev/sdb <destination_folder>`

Run `df-h` or `mount` to check if your disk is already mounted in the destination folder.